# Weblogic wls-wsat component in Payara: CVE-2017-10271

Tags: glassfish, weblogic, shiro, payara

**Question**: I thought Weblogic and GlassFish / Payara are completely different servers and do not share any common code/component. How come I reached a Weblogic CVE when using Payara?

**Configuration**: Both our development and production systems are under Payara:

- Payara 4.1.1.171.1 Full edition
- Oracle Java 1.8.0_144
- CentOS 7

**Symptoms**:

- we have illegal connection to url `/wls-wsat/CoordinatorPortType11` and `wls-wsat/ParticipantPortType`, under Anonymous authentication despite having *Apache Shiro* as security system.
- we have an *unknown Pyhton program running in our Production*. Nothing found in Development so far
- Payara Development has shutdown once and one deployment failed ending having Payara stopped (`start-domain` was required). *Payara Production has shutdown once*. All of it for unknown reason, especially there were at most one or two users doing nothing special at the shutdown moments

**What I can (not) do:**

- After seeing [this](https://github.com/kkirsche/CVE-2017-10271) and reading [this](https://www.alertlogic.com/blog/beware-the-weblogic-wls-wsat-component-deserialization-rce-exploit/), I think the problems is solved for WebLogic systems but I don't know the mapping GlassFish version <-> Weblogic version, if it exists
- Unless I missed a big stuff, I haven't found anything related [CVE-2017-10271](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-10271) and Payara.
- We are planning to upgrade to Payara 4.1.2.174 shortly but I have no guarantee it will fix this issue.
- I'm trying to check how Shiro can block such connection

---

<sub>I'm asking this question to make sure that there is (or not) no relationship between WebLogic and GlassFish/Payara before opening an issue on Payara GitHub. I unsuccessfully tried to run the python script, I don't know Python :(</sub>

Comment: I may be misreading things, but it sounds like someone has tried to use an exploit for a WebLogic vulnerability against your Payara instance. The CVE link you posted contains a link to a GitHub repository which demonstrates the exploit, so it would be easy for someone to find and use this example.

Comment: @Mike That's why I'm surprised that a Weblogic failure apparently apply to Payara...Just in case, I have upgraded our Dev system to 4.1.2.174 but, sorry for noobish question, how can I know if I have to wait for a Payara patch (similar to the Oracle's one) or I need to fix our firewall rules/application security? Additionally, they are consuming a hell of my inbound bandwidth T_T

Comment: The WLS exploit uses the /wls-stat endpoint which isn't available in Payara Server. Is it really a connection or just a connection attempt at the URL `/wls-wsat/CoordinatorPortType11`? If it's just an illegal connection attempt which fails with HTTP 404 Not Found, then it's OK and Payara just refuses such connection.

Comment: @OndrejM Thanks for letting know that the endpoint is not available in Payara (huge relief). AFAIK, connection attempt has been blocked by Apache Shiro, that's the only information I can make sure of. I can't tell you if any exploit was used but strangely enough, we have a bandwidth consumption increase starting from the moment we noticed such connection attempt.

Comment: @OndrejM I'll proceed to production upgrade to 4.1.2.174 and restart soon. I'll wait for like a week to check if it changes things and I'll post a self-answer based on your comment if applicable.